# Batch script for loop counter variable not being update

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a simple batch script to get the first few lines of a text file
but it seems like the counter is not working, i did my research and have tried both `!` and `%` for the `counter` variable, but the `%count%` always return `1` and `!counter!` always return `!counter!`.  what am i missing?

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
Set /a count=1
FOR /F "tokens=*" %i in ('type "C:\Users\Desktop\test.csv"') DO (
if %_count% LEQ 4 (Echo %i)
    set /a count+=1
    echo "count here :" 
    echo %count%
    echo !count!
    )
endlocal
```

Comment: Batch files require `%%` not `%`.

Comment: @Compo when i use %%, it give me the `%%i was unexpected at this time.` error, what i am doing will print out all the lines in the files, just it wont stop at the 4th lines

Comment: Well did you notice that `%_count%` isn't defined? or that it may perhaps need to be `!count!` instead?

Comment: @Compo o god. . . .  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notwithstanding the comments I have already made, you could probably do this an easier way, by using [find](/questions/tagged/find):

```bat
@(For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=[]" %%# In ('^""%__AppDir__%find.exe" /V /N ""^<"C:\Users\Desktop\test.csv"^"')Do @Echo=%%$&If %%# Equ 4 Pause&Exit /B)&Pause
```

If you want that split over a few lines for readability:

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=[]" %%# In (
    '^""%__AppDir__%find.exe" /V /N ""^<"C:\Users\Desktop\test.csv"^"'
)Do @(
    Echo=%%$
    If %%# Equ 4 Pause&Exit /B
)
@Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Looked at this on the phone looks like you aren't executing your loop because of the single % in the loop variable.  You also are using both "_count" and "_count", parenthesis inside the for loop so you would need to fix all these little syntax errors to fix the whole shebang.

```
@(setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
  Echo off
  Set /a "_count=0"
)

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%_ in ('
  type "C:\Users\Desktop\test.csv"
') DO (
  SET /a "_count+=1"
  Echo= : %%_
  IF !_count! GTR 4 ( 
    Endlocal
    Exit /b 0
  )
)
Endlocal
Exit /B 1
```

`SET /A` will echo the variable result at rhe same time its set wirhour appending a newline character so it will end up pre-pending the value in `%%_` and after that will march forward.

Exiting the acript after those four lines are printed shoukd terminate the loop without reading the entire rest of the contents of the file, making it a bit faster.